# Django: Download Excel after User Clicks a Button

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

In my Django project, I need to send an in-memory Excel file to the client side for download. The download should start after the user clicks a button.

Here is my project structure:

```
C:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│   Pipfile
│   Pipfile.lock
│   requirements.txt
│   
├───app
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │       
│   └───templates
│       └───app
│               home.html
│               
└───project
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
```

My `app/forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (
        ('name', 'name'),        
        ('city', 'city')        
    )

    columns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                        choices=OPTIONS)
```

My `app/views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.forms import HomeForm

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template = 'app/home.html'


    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()        
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form})
```

This is my `app/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

My `project/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
]
```

My `app/home.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Generate Data</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Excel">
    </form>

</html>
</body>
```

[The page with the checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyD21.png)

I’m new to Django. How can I get the columns (name, city) as a `list`, create a dictionary `{‘name’: [‘Bob’, ‘Tom’], ‘city’: [‘San Francisco’, ‘Atlanta’]}`, and use the dictionary in the following function, which creates in-memory Excel data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO as IO
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xlsxwriter

def write_to_excel():

    df_output = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Tom'], 'city': ['San Francisco', 'Atlanta']})

    # my "Excel" file, which is an in-memory output file (buffer) 
    # for the new workbook
    excel_file = IO()

    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

    df_output.to_excel(xlwriter, 'sheetname')

    xlwriter.save()
    xlwriter.close()

    # important step, rewind the buffer or when it is read() you'll get nothing
    # but an error message when you try to open your zero length file in Excel
    excel_file.seek(0)

    # set the mime type so that the browser knows what to do with the file
    response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    # set the file name in the Content-Disposition header
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx'

    return response
```

When a user clicks the `Generate Excel` button, the Excel file with the data should be downloaded. I've given all of this code because I think it's necessary for someone to help me.

Comment: What's the problem? Does the file not start downloading, or is it not created, or what?

Comment: @ForceBru, the function creates the Excel, but I don't know how to get the columns as a list and use them in the same function, and it should download after the button is clicked. I think it has to do with `POST` and `GET`.